# How to use "#" symbol using a regular expression as a part of a whole word?

Tags: mysql, regex

Searching for hashtags as part of a singular word (not a portion of a word) in the content like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE LOWER(`messages`.`content`) REGEXP '[[:<:]]#anxiety[[:>:]]'
```

It is not finding any records, however a search for the word "anxiety" works:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE LOWER(`messages`.`content`) REGEXP '[[:<:]]anxiety[[:>:]]'
```

Looking to find messages like "She doesn't like thunderstorms. #anxiety #nervous."

Not looking to match parts of a word like "abc#anxiety". It should match "#anxiety" as a standalone word with a "#" before it like "I have #anxiety", "#anxiety sucks!", or "This is what #anxiety looks like.".

Comment: note that mysql switched regexp libraries in msyql 8 and the :<: syntax is no longer supported.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: should "abc#anxiety" match?

Comment: @ysth the version is "5.6.10-log" and "abc#anxiety" should not be a match only "#anxiety" as a stanalone word with a "#" before it like "I have #anxiety", "#anxiety sucks!", "This is what #anxiety looks like."

Comment: note that that version of mysql is no longer supported (as soon will be true of 5.7 also) and so is now considered insecure.  upgrade as soon as you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you work on MySQL 5.7 as otherwise your first query would not return matches either. See [Regexp compatibility](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#regexp-compatibility) in the MySQL 8 documentation.

Having said that, your second query does not return matches because `#` is a non-alphanumerical character while the `[[:<:]]` pattern requires the character that follows to be alphanumerical. So this will never match. In fact, the mere presence of the `#` prefix already assures that this "anxiety" is not a *part* of a word match at the *left* side, so you should just do:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` 
WHERE LOWER(`messages`.`content`) REGEXP '#anxiety[[:>:]]'
```

In a comment you say that `abc#anxiety` should not match (even though technically `#` already breaks a word). In that case do:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` 
WHERE LOWER(`messages`.`content`) REGEXP '(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_])#anxiety[[:>:]]'
```

In the character class `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` add any other character that you wouldn't allow to precede `#anxiety`.

If your purpose is to find the word with an **optional** `#` in front of it, then use the previous regex with an additional `?`:

```
SELECT * FROM `messages` 
WHERE LOWER(`messages`.`content`) REGEXP '(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9_])#?anxiety[[:>:]]'
```